# taking count from pair values in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image: count_temp table]

take the above as an output of a sample table, 
I need an sql query which results "2" as the count from the table.

i've tried intially while sentby column upto 4, and was okay;
but more rows shows incorrect o/p. my older code is given

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/2
     FROM 
     (SELECT sentby,sentto
     FROM
          (SELECT DISTINCT sentby, sentto FROM count_temp)
     WHERE sentto IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT sentby FROM count_temp )
      AND sentby IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT sentto FROM count_temp )
     ) ;
```

Thanks in advance:) and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
with cte as (
select distinct m1.sentby , m1.sentto
from m m1 
inner join m m2
   on m1.sentby = m2.sentto and
      m2.sentby = m1.sentto 
)
select count(*)/2 from cte;
```

[test it at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f918/4/0)

Also, simplifying:

```
select count( distinct m1.sentby ) / 2
from m m1 
inner join m m2
   on m1.sentby = m2.sentto and
      m2.sentby = m1.sentto
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    SELECT count(*)/2
    FROM
      (SELECT sentby,
              sentto,
              max(rownum) AS rn
       FROM count_temp
       GROUP BY sentby,
                sentto) a,
      (SELECT sentby,
              sentto,
              max(rownum) AS rn
       FROM count_temp
       GROUP BY sentby,
                sentto) b
    WHERE a.rn != b.rn
      AND a.sentby = b.sentto
      AND a.sentto = b.sentby;
```